# Spring: How to access contents of webapp/resources in service layer

Tags: java, spring

How do I access the contents of my webapp/resources folder from the service layer? I need to access a JSON file to be used for Elasticsearch mappings...

This is how my project structure looks like:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/crdzae1ko0x9p89/Screenshot%202015-05-25%2010.24.12.png?dl=0

I tried this:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/

```
String mapping = String.format("es_mappings/%s.json", type);
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        String result = IOUtils.toString(classLoader.getResourceAsStream(mapping));
```

But I got a null pointer exception for the third line in the code snippet above.

Also tried this:

```
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:es_mappings/bom_exports.json")
String txt= FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
```

But I got this error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [es_mappings/bom_exports.json] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system.

I have this in my -servlet.xml file:

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using relative paths depends on the classloader, so you need to either work out where your classloader is looking or else just use an absolute path - 
when using `getResourceAsStream` you need to start with a leading `/` so try this:

```
String mapping = String.format("/es_mappings/%s.json", type);
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    String result = IOUtils.toString(classLoader.getResourceAsStream(mapping));
```

Also I'm not sure the `webapp/resources` folder will be added to the classpath by default in maven. Usually resources like files you need to access at runtime would be in the `src/main/resources` directory. (but I could be wrong, the easy way to tell is check the packaged war file, if the files are in `/WEB-INF/classes` then they are on the classpath)

Comment: I added a leading / and moved my folder to src/main/resources and it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I using this code. It's simple and works.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

// ...

@Value("/resources/json/your_file.json")
private Resource jsonResource;

// ...

InputStream jsonStream = jsonResource.getInputStream();
```

Now you can use stream to read json.

Comment: After spending good 4 hours, the above solution worked just fine. So @Value with no prefix (classpath/file) in the value reads from the root of war file. Also just to confirm what the original post asked for; anything under webapp directory of a maven project by default goes to the root of the war.

Answer (score 1):

```
ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:es_mappings/bom_exports.json")
```

This method get resources file from the webapp/WEB-INF/classes when you pass classpath:*.
If you want get the json file from webapp/resources/es_mappings/your_file.json, the service class can implement the interface ServletContextAware and get servletContext. Because the webapp directory is determined by the web container such as tomcat or jetty, it only get the relative path from servletContext.getResource(). That method can get resources under webapp.
Code example maybe like:

```
class your_service implements ServletContextAware {

     private ServletContext servletContext;

     public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
           this.servletContext = servletContext;
     }

     public void getJsonResource() {
        ...//other code
        String josnFilepath = servletContext.getResource(
                     "/resources/es_mappings/your_file.json");
     }
}
```

Also you can get the webapp directory by finding "WEB-INF/classes" substring in  classpath.

```
String path =  this.getClass().getResource("").getPath();
String fullPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "utf-8");
String pathArr[] = fullPath.split("/WEB-INF/classes/");
if (2 == pathArr.length) { //pathArr[0] is webapp directory path
    String jsonFilepath = pathArr[0] + "/resources/es_mappings/your_file.json";
}
```