# Redirect almost all requests to index.html

Tags: spring-boot, vue-router

I'm creating a web application for which I'm using Vue for the frontend and Spring Boot for the backend. Spring Boot serves index.html at `/` and `/index.html`, but I want it to be served at other URL's too, for example `/account`, which in turn will be detected by Vue's Router and will show the proper page.

Additionally, I have some other URL's I don't want to serve index.html. All of them start with `/api`, meaning that's the place where the Vue app sends requests.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is called an SPA (single page application). In order to achive this you need to do two things:

1. Tell vue-router to use HTML5 history push: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations
2. Tell SpringBoot to serve the index.html when it cannot find a relevant route. Here is a good guide on how to do it using a handler for NoHandlerFoundException: https://medium.com/@kshep92/single-page-applications-with-spring-boot-b64d8d37015d

I have to warn you: when you configure history mode in step 1., click something, it will look like your SPA is already working (no # sign). Beware that this is an illusion. Vue-router tells the browser how the url should look like, but when you refresh the page, the server will return 404. You have to configure step 2 as well.

Comment: I've already done step 1. What I was missing is step 2. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because in my application I do not have only VUE in the user interface, redirect all errors to the VUE index.html as is proposed before is not acceptable in my scenario.

Finally, I have solved in another manner using filters ( basically the idea is to intercept all URL that are not css, js, images, etc... used in my VUE UI and take control of the response). In my case the VUE URL starts with "/context/kmobile/":

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

@Component
public class Html5PathFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Html5PathFilter.class);

    // Capture the content of a file from /webapps/kmobile/index.html
    // Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431025/spring-how-to-access-contents-of-webapp-resources-in-service-layer
    @Value("/kmobile/index.html")
    private Resource indexResource;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String path = request.getServletPath();
            if (!path.endsWith(".css") && !path.endsWith(".js") && !path.endsWith(".ico") && !path.endsWith(".html") &&
                    !path.endsWith("/kmobile/")) {
//              log.info("YES, do redirect ->" + path);

                // Code warning, initially were using redirect, that's a bad practice because from browser get the index.html url what never should be used directly there
                // response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/kmobile/index.html");

                // Disable browser cache
                response.setHeader("Expires", "Sat, 6 May 1971 12:00:00 GMT");
                response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate");
                response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
                response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0, pre-check=0");
                response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
                InputStream is = indexResource.getInputStream();
                // Set MIME type
                response.setContentType("text/html");
                // Content leght
                response.setContentLength(is.available());

                try (ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()) {
                    IOUtils.copy(is, out);
                    out.flush();
                }
                return;
            } else {
//              log.info("NO, do redirect ->" + path);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.debug("Error: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        //log.info("--> {}", request.getServletPath());
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String path = request.getServletPath();
        boolean valid = path.startsWith("/kmobile");
        if (valid) {
            log.info("path: {} => {}", path, valid);
        }
        return !valid;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far, it returns the correct error responses for non UI stuff and index.html for the UI stuff. I was trying to do the same and got your snippet!